# How to use this css :: symbol in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I wanted to change the css attribute of this selector::valuetochange using jquery?

example:

this is my css

```
#au_zip_overlay::labels
```

how to change the property of the 'labels' using jquery?

Thanks

Comment: i don't think you can change pseudo-elements like that.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Best way would be to make different classes i think and then swap out classes with $().removeClass en $().addClass. But, i'm curious to see someone knows a way to edit psuedo selectors.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do, do you want to change the labels attribute value? `$("#au_zip_overlay[labels]").attr("labels", "new value")`

Comment: I just found out that the double column ( :: )is called pseudo element in css.

Comment: I just found out that the double column ( :: )is called pseudo element in css. I wanted to change the property of the pseudo element labels in this css #au_zip_overlay::labels. The pseudo labels has the property text-opacity: 0; . I wanted to change to text-opacity: 1;